# About the voltage usage in house

Tags: voltage

Don't take this the wrong way I am new to electrical stuff, so please help me in understanding my confusion. I have an extension cord with 4 sockets and it's plugged into the house mains 240V at 50/60 Hz and 16 amps. 3 sockets of the extension cord are connected to loads, one is a computer using 240V and 6 amps, the second socket is connected to the TV using 240V and 2 amps, and the third is connected to a phone charger using 240V and 0.35 amps. Now if I connect a load to the 4th socket which requires 3 amps and 240V, will it be able to draw 240 volts from the extension cord, or will it draw less voltage as there are already 3 loads utilizing the 240 v? I know that the amperage will be sufficient for it to work but will the voltage be same as 240v at the 4th socket?

Answer (score 4):

All four sockets on the extension lead are wired in parallel, so they all receive the same voltage.

There *will* be a voltage difference between the plug that supplies the extension lead, and any of the four sockets. This is due to the current flowing in the small but finite resistance of the long lead causing a voltage drop. You can expect this drop to be insignificant in a well made lead.

This voltage drop causes power dissipation in the lead, which is why a long lead must be fully unwound before being used to power heavy loads, to allow it to dissipate this heat while staying at a safe temperature.

Answer (score 0):

In household AC power distribution, all loads are effectively connected in parallel, so everything will get the same voltage, but each load will only draw the current that it requires.

Comment: I'm scratching my head over your use of the word 'effectively'. OToneH, there's nothing 'effective' about the connections being parallel, they are actually parallel. But OTotherH, the literal meaning sounds correct. I think I'd be less confused without the word there.

Comment: @Neil_UK: I was thinking of things fed by separate circuit breakers - not directly in parallel.  Here in North America, we may have different outlets in the same room fed by different breakers.  I understand that the British "ring main' system will have fewer independent circuits than we do here.

Comment: Yes, there's directly in parallel, and 'would be in parallel' if things not intended to drop voltage didn't. I guess I implicitly make that distinction in my answer. I'm very sensitive to nuances in language, even if I don't know myself which expression is best to use. Unfortunately nuance gets lost on people whose first language is not english. I suppose the difference between an electrician's parallel and an EE's parallel is how the breakers and connecting wires are modelled. It sounds like the OP is in neither camp!